# WCF Endpoint not found on first execution, found on second

Tags: c#, wcf

I'll set the scene.

We have a set of WCF Service Hosts *(S1, S2...Sn)* that operate in a chain to process a received message, the first service does some processing and then hands the message to the next service which does some more processing and so on. A final WCF Service *(U)* receives the output of Sn and validates it.

The services *S1, S2,...Sn* are started via .exe files separately from the service *U*. Sevice *U* is started from Visual Studio 2010 from a Unit Test and once its started a message is fired into service s1 for processing. The problem we're seeing is that once service *Sn* attempts to pass the message to service U for validation we are presented with an error:

> There was no endpoint listening at http://localhost:9005/ValidationService.svc

The strange thing is this error only occurs on the first run of the Unit Test. If we were to re-run the test after the initial failure the test would pass without issue (*Sn* successfully passing the message to *U*). However closing services *S1, S2,...Sn* restarting and re-running the unit test causes the "no endpoint listening at..." to be thrown again on the first run of the test.

My thoughts are that service *U* might still be completing its opening processes while service *Sn* tries to send a message to it, however I'm unconvinced, if this was the case how can we be sure service U is open and listening before firing a message into S1?

The service *U* is started by the following code:

```
    public void TestChain()
    {
        var binding = new BasicHttpBinding();

        // Construct service U
        var serviceHostU = new ServiceHost(typeof(ChainContract), "http://localhost:9005");
        serviceHostU.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ChainContractImplementation), binding, "ValidationService.svc");
        serviceHostU.Open();

        //fire message into service s1
        var ep = new EndpointAddress("http://localhost:8777/InputService.svc");
        var inputFactory = new ChannelFactory<ChainContract>(binding, ep);
        var channel = inputFactory.CreateChannel();
        //fire a message into service s1.
        channel.ReceiveMessage(new TestMessage());

        serviceHostU.Close();
        }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have a similar problem on one of my unit tests where i told it to expect A but it got B, so when i re ran it for some reason it expected B despite the code not changing and me still saying expect A. just re running it seems to refresh its memory and it goes duh you want A, i think its something to do with where it stores results that throws it off sometimes

Answer (score 0):

I think your supposition that the first ServiceHost is initialising while the second one makes the call is probably correct.

To handle this, you could hook a delegate to the Opened event of your ServiceHost and run your second service from there.

Comment: Thanks for the response, why would the starting of service U on the second test run be faster than the first run?